# Typescript how to move child nodes in array to parent array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is my json

```
[{"Name":"Ancil Abdul Rahuman","map":{"Core Java":null,"JSP":null,"HTML":"Level 1: Proficient","JavaScript":null,"Spring MVC":null,"SOAP":null,"REST Web Services":null,"Oracle DB":null,"Tomcat":null}},{"Name":"Neha Agrawal","map":{"Core Java":null,"JSP":null,"HTML":null,"JavaScript":null,"Spring MVC":null,"SOAP":null,"REST Web Services":null,"Oracle DB":null,"Tomcat":null}}]
```

I need to move the items from the "map" array into the level where it says "Name"

I tried 
to use map.map but it gives an error

Comment: In your example, Map isnt an array.  You wrote it as a dict.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way in my opinion is to use the spread operator:

```
const responses = [{ 
  "Name": "Ancil Abdul Rahuman", 
  "map": { 
    "Core Java": null, 
    "JSP": null, 
    "HTML": "Level 1: Proficient", 
    "JavaScript": null, 
    "Spring MVC": null, 
    "SOAP": null, 
    "REST Web Services": null, 
    "Oracle DB": null, 
    "Tomcat": null } 
}, { 
  "Name": "Neha Agrawal", 
  "map": { 
    "Core Java": null, 
    "JSP": null, 
    "HTML": null, 
    "JavaScript": null, 
    "Spring MVC": null, 
    "SOAP": null, 
    "REST Web Services": null, 
    "Oracle DB": null, 
    "Tomcat": null } 
}];
const newResponses = responses.map(response => { return { Name: response.Name, ...response.map }; });
console.log(newResponses);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn this object:

```
let input = { 
  "Name": "Neha Agrawal", 
  "map": { 
    "Core Java": null, 
    "JSP": null, 
    "HTML": null, 
    "JavaScript": null, 
    "Spring MVC": null, 
    "SOAP": null, 
    "REST Web Services": null, 
    "Oracle DB": null, 
    "Tomcat": null } 
}
```

into this one:

```
let result = { 
  "Name": "Neha Agrawal", 
  "Core Java": null, 
  "JSP": null, 
  "HTML": null, 
  "JavaScript": null, 
  "Spring MVC": null, 
  "SOAP": null, 
  "REST Web Services": null, 
  "Oracle DB": null, 
  "Tomcat": null
}
```

Use the following:

```
let result = {Name: input.Name, ...input.map};
```